# Is there a .NET type like a (value OR error) discriminated union?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, f#, functional-programming

In C#, I would like to have the option to handle errors in a more “functional” way, rather than always using the default exception-throwing model.  In some scenarios, the throwing model is great, because it allows you to force your code to stop executing if something unexpected happens.  However, the throwing model has several major drawbacks:

1. Exception throwing is basically a whole secondary system of application control flow that subverts the main control flow system.  When a method is called, its body is executed and then effectively control returns to the caller, regardless of whether it was due to a `return` or `throw` statement.  If control returned to the caller from a `throw` statement, control will immediately move to its caller if there is no appropriate `try`/`catch` in scope; whereas if control returned from a `return` statement, control continues as normal.  I know the implementation is way more complicated and subtle than that, but I think that’s an appropriate conceptual summary.  This double system can be generally confusing, both at design time and runtime in different ways.
2. The throwing system gets more awkward in parallel or asynchronous scenarios, as seen in the treatments of errors by `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.  Any exceptions thrown by a `Task` executing are stored in an `AggregateException` and accessed through the `Task.Exception` property by the calling code.  So while the `Task`s execution may be aborted, the calling code must look for errors stored in object properties, using normal C# control flow.
3. Aside from XML comments, there is no metadata about whether a method might throw exceptions, or which it might throw.  Exceptions behave as an alternate form of method output, but are largely ignored by the type system.  For example, the method `int Divide(int x, int y)` could result in either an integer or a `DivideByZeroException`, but the signature of this method does not suggest anything regarding errors.  Conversely, I’ve often heard complaints about Java’s checked exceptions, where every specific exception type a method can throw must be added to its signature, which can get very wordy.  To me the simplest middle ground would be a generic type like `Nullable<T>` that contains either a value or an exception.  A method like `Divide` would then have this signature: `Fallible<int> Divide(int x, int y)`.  Any operations using the result would then need to deal with the error case.  Methods could also take `Fallible` parameters to allow easier chaining.

Here is an implementation of `Fallible` I sketched out:

```
public class Fallible<T> : IEquatable<Fallible<T>> {

    #region Constructors

    public Fallible() {
        //value defaults to default(T)
        //exception defaults to null
    }

    public Fallible(T value) : this() {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Fallible(Exception error) : this() {
        if (error == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(error));
        Error = error;
    }

    public Fallible(Func<T> getValue) : this() {
        if (error == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getValue));
        try {
            this.value = getValue();
        }
        catch(Exception x) {
            Error = x;
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Properties

    public T Value {
        get {
            if (!HasValue) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get Value if HasValue is false.");
            return value;
        }
    }
    private T value;

    public Exception Error { get; }

    public bool HasValue => Error == null;

    #endregion


    #region Equality

    public bool Equals(Fallible<T> other) => (other != null)
        && Equals(Error, other.Error)
        && Equals(Value, other.Value);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Fallible<T>);

    public static bool operator ==(Fallible<T> a, Fallible<T> b) {
        if (a == null) return b == null;
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Fallible<T> a, Fallible<T> b) {
        if (a == null) return b != null;
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        HasValue 
            ? Value.GetHashCode() 
            : Error.GetHashCode();

    #endregion


    public override string ToString() =>
        HasValue
            ? $"Fallible{{{Value}}}"
            : $"Fallible{{{Error.GetType()}: {Error.Message}}}";
}
```

**And the questions:**

1. Is there already something like `Fallible<T>` for .NET?  Perhaps a class in the Task Parallel Library, Reactive Extensions, or the F# core libraries?
2. Are there any major deficiencies in the implementation above?
3. Are there any conceptual problems with control flow that I may be overlooking?

Comment: Not aware of any built in similar construct. The idea is interesting and might have valid use cases, but note that nearly every call to such a method will generally be followed by an if-else to check for errors, while try-catch has the advantage of being able to guard a larger block of logic. Also cascading calls to methods returning `Fallible` might be tricky, while exceptions would bubble up by default without cluttering code that isnt interested in handling them

Comment: Implementation is quite simple and looks ok for me. You can use this approach, but other developers (users of your library or your colleagues) might not be very happy with it (since it goes against how .NET framework itself is designed). But if you use it for yourself - sure, why not.

Comment: Here is an example where F# has just used a 2 element DU https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.catch%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: In general, this approach, or similar ones, is pretty common in F#, but becomes difficult in C#.  You really need exhaustive pattern matching in order for this to become truly useful.

Comment: The exception itself should be thrown if you try to access the value. Thats the same with Task<T>.Result - BTW I like the exception flow

Comment: If you're going to use this, at least make it a struct. If you use that everywhere it'll add an unnecessary strain on the GC, and using a value type avoids that. But IMO it makes for clumsy code as you'll need conditionals everywhere. Pattern matching should change that in the future (not yet for C# 7 though).

Comment: http://higherlogics.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/sasaresult-handling-exceptional-values.html

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - Good point regarding structs.  Forcing calling code to have conditionals or some way of dealing with errors is both the benefit and downside of this error handling scheme.  F# style pattern matching would certainly make it cleaner, and I am rather disappointed that C#7's "pattern matching" is taking the form of a more convoluted `switch` statement rather than an F# port. / @Mauricio Scheffer - The Sasa library looks interesting, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK they want to nail it but they didn't have enough time to do it right for C# 7. There are a lot of subtle issues to handle. Hopefully they'll settle on a nice design for C# 8.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - I was looking over the Roslyn Github page and found a working list of C#8 features.  F#-style pattern matching is included. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md

Comment: @JamesFaix yes, but it's in the "prototyping" stage according to your link. It's a major feature they'll surely want to include in C# 8 though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't anything like this built into the BCL, though FSharp.Core does include support for options, which provide another mechanism by which you can avoid exception handling.

The [Language Ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) project does contain a `Try<T>` type which is very similar to what you're describing.  In addition, it has a C# friendly `Option<T>` with pseudo pattern matching for operations on the options.

Comment: Language Ext is something I've been looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf project is a C# library intended to imitate F# discriminated unions in a generic way. You could use that to implement your own `Result` type as a `OneOf<ResultData, ErrorData>` (where you've defined the `ResultData` and `ErrorData` classes with whatever specific things your data model needs).